# Get top rated item using AVG mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to find top rated item using AVG function in mysql, right now my query looks like this:

```
SELECT a.title, AVG(d.rating) as rating FROM in8ku_content a  
JOIN in8ku_content_ratings d ON a.id = d.article_id 
ORDER BY rating DESC
```

Problem is that it takes AVG of all items and the result is not accurate, what should be changed here to get correct result ?

Tables:

```
in8ku_content [id, title]           in8ku_content_ratings [id, article_id, rating]
```

Comment: before `ORDER BY` clause, add this: `GROUP BY a.title`. also use `avg_rating` instead of `rating` as it may have name collision with the original column name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about trying like this:-

```
SELECT a.title, AVG(d.rating) as rating FROM in8ku_content a  
JOIN in8ku_content_ratings d ON a.id = d.article_id
GROUP BY a.title 
ORDER BY rating DESC
```